# Exception while importing pymorphy2

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, pip

I've installed pymorphy2 using pip:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymorphy2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docopt>=0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pymorphy2)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymorphy2-dicts<3.0,>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pymorphy2)
```

But when I'm trying to import this library in Python interactive shell I get this:

```
>>> import pymorphy2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .analyzer import MorphAnalyzer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/analyzer.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pymorphy2 import opencorpora_dict
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/opencorpora_dict/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .storage import load_dict as load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/opencorpora_dict/storage.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pymorphy2.utils import json_write, json_read
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymorphy2/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import bz2
ImportError: No module named bz2
```

Ok, no problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

And finally:

```
maestro@UIServer:~$ sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libbz2-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python-pip (0.3.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2196, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2190, in main
    rv = action.run(global_options)
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 1478, in run
    runtimes = get_installed_runtimes()
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 279, in get_installed_runtimes
    default_version = pyversions.default_version(version_only=True)
  File "/usr/share/pycentral-data/pyversions.py", line 172, in default_version
    raise ValueError, "/usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to %s" % debian_default
ValueError: /usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.6
dpkg: error processing python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to resolve this conflict with versions of python in my case?

Comment: Do you have multiple version of python? Why don't you update your system before installing some packages?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create a new symbolic link for python 2.6.

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: But we're using python 2.7 in our project on server side. How can I switch it to python 2.6 globally?

Comment: Should I temporarily change the simbolic link to other version of python, or are there might be any different ways to solve this problem?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure and I don't want to tell you something that could mess up your current setup. Hope someone else has answer for you. What I posted is what I wouldn't tried. Managing multiple python versions can end up being a pain if you didn't plan how you were going to do it from the beginning. My response was based on the ValueError in your paste.